# 2 pagecontent on 1 page?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have no idea what this kinda "effect" is called, I tried google my ideas on what it might be called, but with no results.

I tried explaining in a picture.
http://piclair.com/olwpe

When someone clicks either "Grocery/Drinks" as is shown in the example on the picture, the blue content changes, and not going to another page.

I wonder if anyone know where I can find some type of information/guide regarding this.

Comment: this isn't really a concept or an effect, it's... a method... you're just showing and hiding divs, or replacing the content of divs.

Comment: try something about ajax...it's method which allow you to load content into page withou refreshing...or use jquery and some tab switch

Answer (score 2):

You can use hide() and show() to choose which div you want to be visible:

**HTML:**

```
<a class="foo">Show FOO</a>
<a class="bar">Show BAR</a>
<div class="foo">FOO</div>
<div class="bar">BAR</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div.foo{display:block}
div.bar{display:none}
```

**JS:**

```
$("a.foo").click(function() {
   $("div.bar").hide();
   $("div.foo").show();
});
$("a.bar").click(function() {
   $("div.foo").hide();
   $("div.bar").show();
});
```

Or you can just change the content of the div like this:

**HTML:**

```
<a class="foo">Show FOO</a>
<a class="bar">Show BAR</a>
<div>FOO</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$("a.foo").click(function() {
   $("div").html("FOO");
});
$("a.bar").click(function() {
   $("div").html("BAR");
});
```

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work, also tried exact to copy & paste ur code without any result.

Comment: If you are putting the JS in external file or in the head tag, remember to put it in $(document).ready(function() ... });

Answer (score 1):

They are probably using [jQuery load()](https://api.jquery.com/load/).

> Description: Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved in multiple ways!

**1) Ajax goodness**

Requested the data from your server ($.load, $.ajax, good ole xmlhttprequest), and then pop that into your DOM.

Here's a JS fiddle example:
http://jsfiddle.net/y8ghj/

**2) `display:none` goodness**

Grab all your data and throw it into the page. The default content is displayed, but the rest is hidden. Using JavaScript (or even CSS!), you can trigger an event that display for each section.

Here's a JS fiddle example (using jQuery show/hide): http://jsfiddle.net/VKkR9/